Why does LTC6253-7 not perform properly on LTspice?
I am working with LTC6253-7 op amp which should have a bandwidth of 2 GHz but when I simulate the output for a follower and the output is being severely attenuated. Is there a technique that must be used to achieve unity gain? My signal is 500 MHz I am using to test this op amp.



The LT part numbers ending with dashed numbers means the minimum gain for stability.  If you need unity gain stable, I would try the AD8000 recommended to you in your previous question: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8000.html

Also, I noticed you post many questions and never accept any answers.  See this for more info:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

I should also note that most GHz range unity gain opamps will be "current feedback" instead of "voltage feedback".

but you can use them the same way right? so i think its ok.

Ehhhh...mostly, but there are some differences.  One important thing is that CFB opamps usually have a very limited input and output range, so you don't have much headroom operating from a single supply.  Additionally, I think for your application (unity gain buffer) you need to be careful of the feedback resistor.  See Figure 4 and the text above it in the following application note:  https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sboa081

It's quite simple. You are using the device outside it's prescribed limits as stated in the data sheet: -
The device is stable for closed loop noise gains of 7 or higher

In other words, the minimum gain is not unity but 7. More info from the data sheet: -
Gain Bandwidth Product: 2 GHz
–3dB Frequency (AV = 7): 160 MHz


I am working with LTC6253-7 op amp which should have a bandwidth of 2 GHz

No, it has a gain-bandwidth-product of 2 GHz
